# Renaming folders based on a dictionary in form of a CSV file?

Tags: bash, rename, csv

I will describe the problem quite verbose, as I have learned that only talking about a specific sub-problem I have identified leads to missed oppurtunities ... So I will put a tl;dr up front: **There is a set of folders that need to be renamed according to a mapping in a CSV file.**

The folder names follow the following pattern:

```
[[:alpha:]]*[[:digit:]]*_[[:alnum:]]*
```

The digits in the middle are relevant and specify the new name the folder should have. So I could run the following sed command to extract the part of the foldername I am interested in.

```
sed 's/[[:alpha:]]*\([[:digit:]]*\)_[[:alnum:]]*/\1/'
```

So we might have a folder thats named `deptA100257_2bfde391c6af30fde3fca94b07bc8e7c` and can pull out the relevant ID `100257`. I then need to rename the folder according to the following CSV:

```
63;9961
63;100257
```

The new name is on the left, the ID of the old name on the right. So the folder from the example above should be renamed to `63`.

First obvious problem: Multiple Ids may map to a single name. I would solve this by creating all "new" folders up front and copy the folder contents instead.

And I could hack this up using Python or whatever, possibly even some bash loops. But something tells me that at the core, this operation (substitution according to a file) isn't exactly uncommon. So before re-inventing the wheel ...

I prefer solutions using standard *NIX shells and tools (especially bash or zsh) and no "external" languages like Perl, Ruby, Python ... But in the end I am more or less looking for a "smart" approach and if there is a nice Ruby one-liner that gets the job done, I am ok with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `find` to get the folder names, parse them with `sed`, grep the corresponding id and copy stuff over:

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -type d | while read dir; do 
   id=$(echo "$dir" | sed 's/\.\/[[:alpha:]]*\([[:digit:]]*\)_[[:alnum:]]*/\1/'); 
   new_name=$(grep -w "$id" names.csv | cut -d ';' -f 1); 
   mkdir -p "$new_name" && mv -rv "$dir"/* "$new_name"/ && rmdir "$dir"; 
 done
```

The tricks are

- use `mkdir -p` which will create the directory and exit silently if it exists.
- use `grep -w` on the csv file to only get those lines that contain the entire ID bordered by non-word characters. That way you avoid matching both `1123` and `123` for the id `123`.

Comment: That `rmdir` would fail as the directory is not empty,  Maybe `mv -v "$dir"/* "$new_name"/`? Also need to be careful you don't require `.` files from the base directory when copying/moving with the `*` glob.

Comment: @mindthemonkey of course it would *facepalm*. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your directories are all under current working directory, here is a starting point (so **test it** before running in prod):

```
csvFile="/tmp/file.csv"

for d in ./*; do
  # only work with directory
  [[ ! -d "$d" ] && continue

  # extract id from directory
  id="$(echo "$d" | sed 's/[[:alpha:]]*\([[:digit:]]*\)_[[:alnum:]]*/\1/')"

  # fetch new name
  nid="$(awk -F';' '/'"$id"'/ {print $1}' "$csvFile")"

  # merge all matching dir into one
  mv "$d" "$nid"
done
```

### Utilities

Did you look at :

- [`mmv`](http://ss64.com/bash/mmv.html): Mass Move and rename ;
- [`zmv`](http://zshwiki.org/home/builtin/functions/zmv): a `zsh` module that allow people to do massive rename.

Comment: Nice but your `gawk` will match any lines containing the id, not only those that have the _specific_ id. It will match both `foo123` and `123bar` for the id 123 for example. It will also create subdirectories rather than copying files for the second folder with the same target id.

Comment: your description did not expose the possibility of ambiguous id. I'm aware my script is not *the* solution, just a useful proposition :)

Comment: It's quite clearly stated in the OP. It's both shown in the example and explicitly mentioned: "First obvious problem: Multiple Ids may map to a single name. I would solve this by creating all "new" folders up front and copy the folder contents instead."